# Why is the interface different for different instagram account

Tags: python, selenium, interface, instagram

I am using selenium python to send a message to a user.I made my code and it was working for an account but when I tried with a different account the interface was totally different
For example -
in my first account
[image]
you can see the message icon is in the left side and I made my program according to that xpath,but now I signed up with a different account and the interface and xpath was totally different like -
[image]

How would I handle this type of bug in selenium python or How can I identify which account has which interface?
thankyou for your time

I tried to message a username through selenium and I expected the xpath for every account will be same but it was not

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just prepare code for both interfaces. Then check which one is loaded at the page opening and use the appropriate code version. If you are trying to create a bot for some service you have no guarantee the elements will always be the same.

Comment: Sir what is the best way to do madd dm to followers of instagram for marketing.I am using selenium but the xpath is changing a lot.Is there any better option

Comment: Can you locate the elements by Id or class names? there must be some same factors for elements in both interfaces.